# Saving string variables in a custom EditorWindow while formatted like a TextArea

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

Basically, I want to figure out how I can:

1. **Save string (or any) variables in a custom editor window (inheriting
   from EditorWindow) when they are changed in that window.**
2. **Display strings in a format like a TextArea while still allowing
   saving changes as mentioned above.**
3. **Display strings from a string array by index, rather than individually defined strings (I've had trouble with this before)**
4. If you know how to do the above in a custom inspector too
   (inheriting from Editor, not EditorWindow), that'd be great too.

I've run into this issue a few times with different classes inheriting from Editor, and previously solved by using a PropertyField rather than a TextArea/TextField, but that gets rid of the TextArea-style formatting that I want.
Also, classes inheriting from EditorWindow don't seem to allow it in the same way (`t = (script type)target;` doesn't work, and PropertyField needs it)..?

I'm pretty new to custom inspectors and this stuff, so code examples would be super helpful if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting a general note because you mentioned it in your question:

Whenever possible I strongly recommend to avoid using `target` at all! In particular do not set any fields directly. this makes things like marking your scene *direty* and thus saving changes and also Undo/Redo functionality pretty complicated as you will have to implement it by yourself!

Rather always go through [`SerializedProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) combined with [`SerializedObject.Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.Update.html) and [`SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties.html) (examples will be below). This handles all this stuff like marking *dirty* and thus saving the scene changes and Undo/Redo automatically for you!

---

Then to the TextArea.

Lets say you have a class like

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _exampleString;
    public string AnotherExampleString;
}
```

Basically there are three main options. I will do the `Editor` (custom Inspector) script first since there you are a bit more flexible.

The `EditorWindow` will be below.

---

#### Editor Attribute [`[TextArea]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAreaAttribute.html)

Actually you wouldn't even need an `Editor` script at all! Simply tag the according field(s) as [`[TextArea]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAreaAttribute.html) like this:

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] [TextArea] private string _exampleString;
    // You can also directly configure the min and max line count here as well
    // By default it is 3 lines
    [TextAre(3,7)] public string AnotherExampleString;
}
```

This already looks like this

[image]

---

#### [`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html)

Then **if** you still need the `Editor` script the good thing about a [`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) is it automatically uses the correct drawer for the according type ... and it **also applies all editor attributes**! Isn't this great?

So simply having and `Editor` like

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(Example))]
public class ExampleEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _exampleString;
    private SerializedProperty AnotherExampleString;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Link in the serialized properties to their according fields
        _exampleString = serializedObject.FindProperty("_exampleString");
        AnotherExampleString = serializedObject.FindProperty("AnotherExampleString");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        // load the real target values into the serialized properties
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_exampleString);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(AnotherExampleString);

        // write back the changed properties into the real target
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    // Little bonus from my side so you have the script field on top
    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((Example)target), typeof(Example), false);
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    }
}
```

The result looks basically exactly the same:

[image]

#### [`EditorGUILayout.TextField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextField.html)

Using a [`EditorGUILayout.TextArea`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextArea.html) you can display **any** `string` as a multi-line text area. This also applies to an `EditorWindow`.

Lets say again we didn't tag our `string` fields

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _exampleString;
    public string AnotherExampleString;
}
```

But we can make them appear just as before using this `Editor` script:

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(Example))]
public class ExampleEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _exampleString;
    private SerializedProperty AnotherExampleString;

    private Vector2 scroll1;
    private Vector2 scroll2;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Link in the serialized properties to their according fields
        _exampleString = serializedObject.FindProperty("_exampleString");
        AnotherExampleString = serializedObject.FindProperty("AnotherExampleString");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawScriptField();

        // load the real target values into the serialized properties
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(_exampleString.displayName);
        scroll1 = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll1,GUILayout.MaxHeight(3 * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
        _exampleString.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(_exampleString.stringValue, EditorStyles.textArea);
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(AnotherExampleString.displayName);
        scroll2 = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll2, GUILayout.MaxHeight(7 * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
        AnotherExampleString.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(AnotherExampleString.stringValue);
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        // write back the changed properties into the real target
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    // Little bonus from my side so you have the script field on top
    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((Example)target), typeof(Example), false);
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    }
}
```

Though you can see we already had to fake it a bit using the additional [`EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView.html)

---

This same thing you can also do in an `EditorWindow`. Most of the times it makes not much sense to go through `SerializedProperty` for `EditorWindow`

```c#
public class ExampleWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private string exampleString;
    private Vector2 scroll;

    [MenuItem("Example/Show ExampleWindow")]
    private static void Initialize()
    {
        var window = GetWindow<ExampleWindow>();
        window.Show();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("Example String");
        scroll = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll,GUILayout.MaxHeight(3 * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
        exampleString = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(exampleString, EditorStyles.textArea);
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the brilliant answer! I'll definately be refering back to this in future :)
Secondly, the EditorWindow section at the bottom of your answer looks very familiar to what I have, but my text area's still dont save their values after clicking outside of the area. I have 3 seperate strings, and if I edit one then click away or in another, the first reverts to empty.

Comment: Just made a script containing your code and it worked correctly, so the problem is in mine somewhere...

Comment: Its a bit long (347 lines). Shall I post here, or can you suggest a better way? (New to this website too :) )

Comment: You could also do it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and only add the link here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aBxNhCnv
The second class is the EditorWindow, first class is just dealing with the data and other system functions. The first is probably not too important but I included it just in case.

Comment: Hm I didn't go through all your code (I can't confirm it since in particular I don't have all your used types like `CSVLoader` etc). However: It seems like you would be better of not using static values for editing but rather use a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) in order store all your values. They are like data containers which live in the assets so you can reference them from everywhere ..

Comment: The main issue however lies in the line **261** `value[i] = LocalizationSystem.GetLocalisedValue(key);` This in every call of `OnGUI` loads the **current** value (which in your case is empty) into the array and overwrites any unsaved changes. You don't see it since Unity keeps the value until the field loses focus but then you see the actual value which is always the one you currently have in your CSV ;) You should add a `bool isLoaded` in order to only load **once** until you either save or change the Key

Comment: Btw: For the Key I would rather use an [`EditorGUILayout.Popup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) so you can select the key from a dropdown of all valid keys instead ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the pointers. How would you suggest I track if it has been "saved or changed"? E.g. When I click away from the text area, save the new input. Is there already a way to track that?

Comment: Within the blocks for `Add/Edit` and `Remove` you could simply set the `isLoaded` to false again so you know you have to load the values in now. Same you can do when the `key` is changed via `EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck(); key = EditorGUILayout.TextField(key); if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()){ isLoaded = false; }`

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll start making all those changes and see if I can get it working ;)
Many thanks for all the help!